# How to access root in AS3?

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3

So after of hours of trying to figure out why my code isn't compiling, I come to find out that this code is incompatible for AS3:

```
function loadXML(loaded) {
if (loaded) {
_root.inventor = this.firstChild.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
_root.comments = this.firstChild.childNodes[0].childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue;
name_txt.text = _root.inventor;
comment_txt.text = _root.comments;
} else {
  trace("file not loaded!");
}
}

xmlData = new XML();
xmlData.ignoreWhite = true;
xmlData.onLoad = loadXML;
xmlData.load("http://localhost/connect.php");
```

Anyone know how to access the root in AS3? Thanks!

Comment: I might be wrong, but didn't they remove the root variable in AS3?

Comment: If I knew, I wouldn't be asking? :) Any idea how I access the XML tree?

Comment: This code is 100% AS2 (not only the _root part)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up...made a little progress. Found something on using E4X and I think it might work, but a ton of crap still to look over in order to figure out how to make it do what I want to. (http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=13_Working_with_XML_08.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I ended up doing:

```
var myXML:XML = new XML();
var XML_URL:String = "http://localhost/connect.php";
var myXMLURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(XML_URL);
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(myXMLURL);
myLoader.addEventListener("complete", xmlLoaded);

function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void
{
    var finalXML:XML = XML(myLoader.data);
    //trace(finalXML);
    trace("Data loaded.");
    //trace(finalXML.triviaQuestion[0].answer1[0]);
    //questionBox.text = (finalXML.triviaQuestion[0].question[0]).toString();
}
```

Comment: So are your saying that this is the answer to your own question or that it's an update? If it's an update, you should add it to your question probably underneath a **[UPDATE]** tag and then delete this answer.

Comment: This looks good. It's best to avoid using root in AS3 as a place to store data since it violates OOP principles.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the root `Sprite` or `MovieClip`  (document class) of the movie, you can just use the property `root` of any `DisplayObject` on the stage.

Answer (score 0):

Use `MovieClip(root)` instead of just `_root`, it works!
Like this:

```
function loadXML(loaded){
 if (loaded) {
  MovieClip(root).inventor = this.firstChild.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
  MovieClip(root).comments = this.firstChild.childNodes[0].childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue;
  name_txt.text = MovieClip(root).inventor;
  comment_txt.text = MovieClip(root).comments;
 } else {
  trace("file not loaded!");
 }
}

xmlData = new XML();
xmlData.ignoreWhite = true;
xmlData.onLoad = loadXML;
xmlData.load("http://localhost/connect.php");
```